# Smooth scrolling down after component with pdf is displayed in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I would need smooth scrolling down to component with generated pdf. But it looks like that first is scrolled to view and then
component is mounted. How can I set waiting to component is displayed and then scroll to view this component?
When I click to button, the pdf will start to generate. After generating this pdf, I would like scroll to view this PDFViewer.

My solution does not work. 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression. OR Object is possibly 'null'.

I use reactjs 17.0.2, react-pdf/renderer 3.0.1, typescript.

Code:

```
import { PDFViewer } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

export const Print: NextPage = () => {
  const [pdfGenerationEnabled, setPdfGenerationEnabled] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const generatePDFAndView = async () => {
    setPdfGenerationEnabled(true);
    await document.getElementById("generated-pdf-view")?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }

  return (
    <DownloadAndPrint>
      <h2>Generating PDF</h2>
      <p>
        Some long text
        Some long text
        Some long text
        .
        .
        .
      </p>
      <Button
        className="btn-generate-pdf"
        onClick={() => { generatePDFAndView() }}
      >
        Vygenerovať pdf súbory
      </Button>
      {pdfGenerationEnabled
        ? 
          <>
            <div id="generated-pdf-view" className="viewer-styled">
              <PDFViewer showToolbar={true} style={{ height: "45vh", width: "100%" }}>
                <ComponentPrint 
                  data={data}
                />
              </PDFViewer>
            </div>
          </>
        : ""
      }
    </DownloadAndPrint>
  );
};
```

**EDITED:** After added delay, it's works. After 3 seconds smooth scrolled to the pdf viewer. But I don't know how many seconds it should waiting? Sometimes generated pdf has 3 pages, sometimes 300 pages. According to the data.

```
const delay = (n) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, n*1000));

const generatePDFAndView = async () => {
  setPdfGenerationEnabled(true);
  await delay(3.0);  // waiting 3s
  document.getElementById("generated-pdf-view")?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

Comment: Let's try to think without pdf.
Page is rendered. `<div id="generated-pdf-view">` does not exist on rendered page.
User click on button, then useState pdfGenerationEnabled is set to true. 
Then is called `scrollIntoView()` to non-existent `<div id="generated-pdf-view">` and then is displayed `<div id="generated-pdf-view">`.
How to do it the other way around?
1. to display the <div id="generated-pdf-view">
2. to call `scrollIntoView()`

Comment: In browser it's iframe. `<div class="viewer-styled"><iframe src="blob:http://localhost:3100/003d8d07-4277-43d5-9691-9b78afed3305#toolbar=0" style="height: 35vh; width: 100%;"></iframe></div>`

Comment: I edited question. After added delay, it's works. But I don't know how many seconds it should waiting?

Comment: I tried with toolbar id: `document.getElementById("toolbar")?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });` It isn't works also with `delay()`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution with delay and calculation time to wait according to the data. Maybe somebody it helps.

```
import { PDFViewer } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

export const Print: NextPage = () => {
  const [pdfGenerationEnabled, setPdfGenerationEnabled] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const itemsPerPage = 5;

  const calculateTimeToDisplayPdfViewer = () => {
    const numberOfItems = data?.items?.length;
    if (numberOfItems > 0 && itemsPerPage > 0) {
      let time = (numberOfItems / itemsPerPage) / 5;  // 1 page = 1/5s = 0.20s
      time = parseFloat(time.toFixed(2));
      console.log("Waiting " + time + "s.");
      return time;
    } else {
      return 2.0;
    }
  }

  const delay = (n) => new Promise( r => setTimeout(r, n*1000));  // waiting in seconds

  const generatePDFAndView = async () => {
    setPdfGenerationEnabled(true);
    await delay(calculateTimeToDisplayPdfViewer());
    document.getElementById("generated-pdf-view")?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }

  return (
    <DownloadAndPrint>
      <h2>Generating PDF</h2>
      <p>
        Some long text
        Some long text
        Some long text
        .
        .
        .
      </p>
      <Button
        className="btn-generate-pdf"
        onClick={() => { generatePDFAndView() }}
      >
        Vygenerovať pdf súbory
      </Button>
      {pdfGenerationEnabled
        ? 
          <>
            <div id="generated-pdf-view" className="viewer-styled">
              <PDFViewer showToolbar={true} style={{ height: "45vh", width: "100%" }}>
                <ComponentPrint 
                  data={data}
                />
              </PDFViewer>
            </div>
          </>
        : ""
      }
    </DownloadAndPrint>
  );
};
```